# Bash Script to get the logs of the day

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a bash script to get the daemon.logs of the day with the specific words and send it per mail to me. Here is my script which sends all the logs but i just want the logs of the day. For example today is 16/09/16 i want all the logs for 16/09/16. i really appreciate if anyone can help me.

```
 #!/bin/bash

    EMAIL="foobar@foo.com"
    DIR="/var/log/daemon.log"
    FILTER="named.*denied|named.*transfer"


    egrep "$FILTER" "$DIR" | mail -s "DNS Query and Transfers on $(date +%F)" $EMAIL
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the date is stored in the beginning of the log line, as YYYY/MM/DD. Just extend the egrep pattern:

```
egrep "^$(date +%Y/%m/%d).+$FILTER" | ....
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i really appreciate it, i tried it but doesn't work. Here is example of a log line:   Sep 16 00:08:19 birch named[31524]: client 85.159.233.131#29007: query (cache) 'cpsc.gov/ANY/IN' denied

Comment: Read my posting carefully: I said *I assume the date is stored in the beginning of the log line, as YYYY/MM/DD*. You say that your line starts with *Sep 16 00:08:19 birch named....*, which is, BTW, **different** from what you stated in your posting. It's obvious that you have to adapt the regexp pattern accordingly, if your lines look differently. Garbage in, garbage out...